# error while sniffing nodes - Timeout connecting to ip adress

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jpa

I'm migrating from Springboot 2.4.0 to 2.7.17. I'm using java 11 and elasticsearch version 7.10.1. When I run the project, it runs well, creates the db and inserts all the row, but after 4-5mins I get the error: `org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer$Task: error while sniffing nodes - java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [/172.17.0.2:9200]` I checked in Docker and 172.17.0.2 is used in the elasticsearch container in the ""IPAddress" tag. After recieving the error, the project continue to run and the backend seems to work well with the elasticsearch features.

**application.yaml** looks like this:

```
    setup:
      admin-account: "..."
    security:
      jwt:
        validity-minutes: 60
    elastic:
      reindex:
        cron: "0 0 3 * * ?"

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          schema_management:
            strategy: drop-and-create-and-drop
          backend:
            hosts: localhost:9200
            protocol: http
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    enabled: true
    contexts: test_1
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB

logging:
  level:
    de.bbht: WARN
    org:
      springframework:
        security: WARN
  config: "./config/logback.xml"

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    operations-sorter: "method"

server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

and **application-local.yaml** looks like this:

```
    cors:
      allowed-origins:
        - "http://localhost:8080"
        - "http://localhost:4200"
    security:
      jwt:
        secret: ...
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?useSSL=false
    username: postgres
    password:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: "..."
    password: "..."
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
logging:
  level:
    de.bbht: DEBUG
    org:
      docx4j:
        model:
          datastorage: DEBUG
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

I tried to upgrade to the elasticsearch image version 7.17.3, but same error.

I treid to add

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: elasticsearch
      cluster-nodes: localhost:9200
      repositories:
        enabled: true
```

on my application.yaml file, but didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean that the backend works well with the elasticsearch features? Check if your elasticsearch docker image exposes the tcp 9200 port to the outside or not.

Comment: By that I mean that the data on the front appears correctly and the requests-responses are working well. I checked and the image exposes 9200 port.